# On dropping a component its adding it more than once on droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using custom helper method which is returning a `<div>`, on dropping that `<div>` its adding it more than one time. Please look at the code to understand it better

```
var dropHelp = true;


$(".product").draggable({
revert: 'invalid',
cursorAt: { top: -12, left: -20 },
 connectToSortable: ".droppable",
helper: function(event) {
  return $('<div class="helper">Helper</div>');
}
});
$(".droppable").sortable({
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
}).disableSelection();
$(".droppable").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if(dropHelp){
       //clone and remove positioning from the helper element
       var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone(false)
           .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
           .css({position:'relative', left:0, top:0});            
       $(this).append(newDiv);

    //drop the draggable source element
    } else {
       $(this).append(ui.draggable);
    }
 }
 });

$('#dropDrag').click(function(){
dropHelp = !dropHelp;
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<button id="dropDrag">Toggle drop "Helper" or "Draggable"</button><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="product">Product 1</div>
<div class="product">Product 2</div>
<div class="product">Product 3</div>

<div class="droppable">Drop Target</div>
```

The full code can be find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6J3AB/).

I found out if we remove the `connectToSortable` property in draggable it will work fine. But i need that property and i am not getting the reason why it's behaving this way when `connectToSortable` is set.

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `drop()` gets called twice because `connectToSortable` is also triggering a `drop()`.
(Sortable is already a droppable)

I have edited your code to get the same result with `receive` function of sortable

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6J3AB/3/)**

```
var dropHelp = true;


  $(".product").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursorAt: { top: -12, left: -20 },
     connectToSortable: ".droppable",
    helper: function(event) {
      return $('<div class="helper">Helper</div>');
    },
      stop: function(){
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
    },
       start: function(){
        $(this).css({opacity:0});
    },
  });
  $(".droppable").sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      receive: function(event, ui) {
          if(dropHelp){
           //clone and remove positioning from the helper element
           var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone(false)
               .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
               .css({position:'relative', left:0, top:0});            
           $(this).append(newDiv);

        //drop the draggable source element
        } else {
           $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        }

  }
  }).disableSelection();


$('#dropDrag').click(function(){
    dropHelp = !dropHelp;
});
```

Comment: Its worth mentioning that a sortable is already a droppable, we don't have explicitly declare it...

Comment: Why is it adding both the helper <div> as well as the original component we dragged? Though we are only adding helper <div> in our receive function.

Comment: @Ashok your draggable is connected to a sortable that is a draggable too. You were calling droppable twice because of this. Now in your receive function you are managing drag event too.

Comment: Thanks @faby i got the reason why its behaving this way. Do you have any idea how we can avoid calling drop in this scenario. So, that the actual parent shouldn't get added to the 'droppable'.

Comment: @Ashok I don't understand very well what you are asking me. Which is the correct behavior that you would reach? You don't want to add helper inside sortable?

Comment: @faby I want to add helper inside sortable. But don't want to add any of the product's <div>, but in the demo its adding both helper as well as the product's <div> inside sortable.

Comment: @Ashok ok i have understand. Give me a little time that now I am on mobiile and i will update my answer for your new request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57477/discussion-between-ashok-and-faby).

Comment: I've updated the answer
let me know if now is what you you want